# Securing settings in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I am working with ASP.NET 5 in an effort to get some web apps ready to port when it goes mainstream.  One of the things I haven't been able to find yet is a way to secure configuration settings.  In previous versions, everything was stored in the web.config which could then be encrypted.  Now it appears that the place to store settings is in appsettings.json.  I understand this concept, but there doesn't appear to be any facility for encrypting or protecting the data stored there.  I'm specifically concerned about:

- The connection string which may contain a username/password at some point
- A flag enabling authorization on the site

There may be other settings that I need to store as well.  Can anyone tell me how to securely store this information in ASP.NET5 / MVC6?

Comment: This is what things like [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) were created for.

Comment: You can put some things in environment variables as well, instead of config files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working in a government facility under severe security restraints and using something like Azure Key Vault which would store information offsite would be strictly prohibited.

Comment: How is storing something in an environment variable any more secure than just putting the setting in appsettings.json?  If physical access to the machine is compromised, environment variables are just as prone to the breech as any files on the computer.  That's why I was hoping for something like the encryption offered by web.config.

Comment: For a connection string, should you not be using Integrated Security=SSPI rather than having the user name and password in a config file? That way, the password for the account is only needed to configure the app pool as part of the deployment process. If that's not your standard then I guess you're into rolling your own encryption.

Comment: @DrewB I meant things like it in general - like a (H)ardware (S)ecurity (M)odule. HSMs are the way to go if high security is required.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I'll definitely look into that.